# Regex for Capturing Group ( )* that return result set with its all occurrence using PHP

Tags: php, regex, multiple-instances

I am new in Regex and facing some trouble in getting my desire results.
I am having string which have three clause:

1) It starts with word 'I' and any other single word after it
2) It starts with any single word and ends with word 'water'
3) It stars with word 'have' and have multiple words after it

Now here the second clause can come zero or many times so I am using * quantifier for it.

But when I perform match and get its results, it only returns the last occurrence of second group or clause.

I am using this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/zxfAB7/6)

and the php code is:

```
<?php

preg_match("/(I(?:\s+\w+))(\s+\w+\s+water)*\s+(have(?:\s+\w+)*)/","I have cold water warm water have some water",$m);

print_r($m);

?>
```

It give output like

```
Array (  
[0] => I have cold water warm water have some water  
[1] => I have  
[2] => warm water  
[3] => have some water  
)
```

But I want the output should be like

```
Array (  
[0] => I have cold water warm water have some water  
[1] => I have  
[2] => cold water  
[3] => warm water  
[3] => have some water  
)
```

It does have any good solution? If no, please suggest any alternative solution.  Thanks

Comment: It is expected, you only can get the text captured with the last iteration of the quantfied capturing group. Capture that repeated capturing group and then split.

Comment: Can you explain please, how to capture that repeated group and how to split.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/HBQhLQ

Comment: Yes...! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: But this solution will have increasing compilation time if multiple occurrence group, occurrence increases

Comment: You do not have a much better choice unless you want to try https://ideone.com/hohOEw, but you wil still need to manipulate the matches.